# Object properties

Tags: php, oop, class

**Is the only way to assign** `$systime` **a value of a built-in-functions, is through a method?**

```
class Test{
    private  $systime;
    public function get_systime(){
       $this->systime = time();
    }
}
```

**Right off i would think something like this right?:**

```
class Test{
    private  $systime = time();
    public function get_systime(){
      echo $this->systime;
    }
}
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a constructor to assign the value, for example:

```
class Test {
  private $systime;
  function __construct() {
    $this->systime = time();
  }

  public function get_systime(){
    echo $this->systime;
  }
}


$t = new Test();
$t->get_systime();
```

For more information on __construct() see the [php manual section on object oriented php.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php (Just before Example 3)

> The default value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function
>   call.

However, you can also assign a value from the constructor:

```
class Test{
    private  $systime;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->systime = time();
    }
    public function get_systime(){
      echo $this->systime;
    }
}
```